# Injecting field content to html.tpl.php in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to make one content type that can reuse a jQuery-gallery with different styles depending on what page you're on.

So i made one field called field_CSS where I put the CSS. However for performance reasons (and for the sake of cleaning up the code) I want to put it in the HEAD-section.

The content in the head section is rendered in the html.php.tpl-filde and the field is in the content type of the specific node.

I've tried `<?php print render($content['field_CSS']) ?> 
<?php print render($page['field_CSS']) ?> 
<?php print $node->field_CSS[0]['view']; ?>` and a lot of other variants. Anyone who knows what to write to make it show up in the html.tpl.php file?

The field only contains pure CSS that now is printed as inline-code.

EDIT: Clive post works flawlessly. Just don't forget to fix the field theming so you don't get a div in the css-section.

Answer (score 3):

The node is not usually available in html.tpl.php so you'll need to get your field content manually in a preprocess function. Put something like this in your theme's template file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();

  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    $node = node_load($node->nid);

    node_build_content($node);

    $vars['extra_css'] = render($node->content['field_CSS']);
  } 
}
```

Then you'll have the variable `$extra_css` in html.tpl.php which will contain your rendered field. You'll need to flush the caches once you've implemented the preprocess function and replace `MYTHEME` with the name of your theme.

Hope that helps

Comment: So, I added  the code to template.php and I added the $extra_css in the html.tpl.php-file.

html.tpl.php looks like <?php print $extra_css; ?>

And the content (not css right now, just text) does not show up on the page. However, the message "var extra_css is not defined" has gone so it should be visible. (Yes, i flushed cache etc)

Thanks for such a quick answer

Comment: My bad I forgot how `node_build_content()` works, I'll correct the code in the post above

Comment: Disregarding the potential of sounding totally gay i must say that i absolutely love you dude.

For the others reading this: Don't forget to change the field display options in field--field_FIELDNAME.tpl.php in your themefolder.

Do you have the link to a good tutorial for these kinds of things?

Comment: Glad it helped :) It's a bit tricky to think of specific tutorials because this method uses a few different Drupal disciplines, there's a good [About overriding themeable output](http://drupal.org/node/173880) page which explains how the theme lifecycle works and how you can pass variables to a theme. How you get those variables in the first place is a different story though, `menu_get_object()` will always get you the node object if you're on a node page, armed with that you should be able to get a good grounding

Comment: Thanks a lot, I mean a fully functional fix (complete with code and all) within less than 30 min is better than premium support at most companies.