# How do I use custom css only for nodes created by a custom module in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a custom module in Drupal 7 that creates nodes.  I want a custom css stylesheet (customstyle.css) applied when one of the nodes created by my custom module is rendered, but *only* when one of the nodes created by my custom module is rendered.

The simple solution (adding `stylesheets[all][] = customstyle.css` to my custom module's .info-file) applies the style sheet to *all* pages, including pages containing nodes *not* created by my custom module. I do not want that.

Comment: You will need to create a preprocess function in your theme folder to add the CSS required depending on the node type. You will have to implement template_preprocess_html. There is a good answer by Clive covering a similar functionality here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7354562/1027644

Comment: Also, this is assuming that your node creates a custom node type, that will allow you to differentiate between nodes created by that module and nodes not created by that module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that "nodes created by my custom module" means that they have some special node type. If so, you can implement `hook_node_view()` in your module and then call `drupal_add_css()` based on the node type or any other property:

```
function mymodule_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  if ($view_mode != 'rss') {
    if ($node->type == 'mynodetype') {
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mynodetype.css');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the site builder way. Use [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) to target that node type, then assign the reaction to load your CSS file, just use `.context-[node type]` to target specific elements in those pages.

For example if your node type is apple recipes, you can use `.context-apple-recipes`